# Can't connect to mqtt broker

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt, mosquitto

I installed MQTT broker Mosquitto on my pi and are having some problems getting it to work with boxes in my network. Locally, if I putty in to the RPi running the Mosquitto MQTT broker everything is OK. I can use the client commands (`mosquitto_sub, mosquitto_pub`) to subscribe and publish to topics, no problem. BUT, if I try to connect from another box, Win2k12 server with a python script it states it cant connect.

- I've tried turning the firewall off in my router
- I've tried turning the firewall off on my Win2k12 server
- I've added TCP 1883 to allowed ports outbound from my Win2k12 server

The Python script:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    client.publish("test_mqtt", "test")
    client.subscribe("test")

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    print("Disconnect, reason: " + str(rc))
    print("Disconnect, reason: " + str(client))

client = mqtt.Client("testclient")
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
client.connect("192.168.1.20", 1883, 60)
client.loop_forever()
```

The output here is

```
Disconnect, reason: <paho.mqtt.client.Client object at 0x01F41EF0>
Disconnect, reason: 1
```

I've tried to have a look at [the documentation](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/docs/#callbacks) but it only mentioned the flags, not defining what they are.

The raspberry pi that is running Mosquitto is also running Node-red. It has no problem connecting to the MQTT broker (both of them are running on the same rpi)

Has enyone set up MQTT on Raspberry Pi and got it to work with other devices? I want it to work with a NodeMCU thingy, but when I had problems I started working on a python script to further debug the problem.

Comment: Are you reusing client ids? ("testclient") every client needs a unique id

Comment: @hardillb I just ran a test with a random client id in the python script, same result.

Comment: what version of mosquitto are you running. new versions of paho uses MQTT 3.11 and old versions of mosquitto only support 3.1

Comment: @hardillb I runs v3.1. So the python lib might be based on 3.11 and not compatible? funny how node-red seems to work

Comment: 3.1 is not the mosquitto version but the protocol version, but if it just says 3.1 then you should upgrade anyway as it's VERY old.

Comment: @hardillb tried a apt-get update but changed nothing

Comment: run `mosquitto -h` the version will be in the first line of output

Comment: @Jason94 Is raspberry and Win2k12 on the same network? Can Win2k12 server access Node Red installed on raspberry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force the paho client to use the 3.1 level of the protocol by adding an option to the mqtt.Client constuctor:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    client.publish("test_mqtt", "test")
    client.subscribe("test")

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    print("Disconnect, reason: " + str(rc))
    print("Disconnect, reason: " + str(client))

client = mqtt.Client("testclient", protocol=mqtt.MQTTv31)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
client.connect("192.168.1.20", 1883, 60)
client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: did not solve the problem, still cant connect and get the same error as before. Had to add "" making it "MQTTv31"

Comment: @hardillib ALLRIGHT! protocol=mqtt.MQTTv31 made the difference and my python script is now working! YAY!

Comment: You should still try to find a newer version of mosquitto

Comment: See https://mosquitto.org/2013/01/mosquitto-debian-repository/ for getting a more up to date version of mosquitto.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make sure that you can connect to the Raspberry Pi. You can try using libraries other than Paho or using one MQTT client:
http://www.hivemq.com/blog/seven-best-mqtt-client-tools

The other thing you can try is setting both client and broker to use port 80 to see if they can communicate through that port.